# Login window ignores context values set by custom auth plugin

Tags: objective-c, macos, authentication, authorization

I'm working on implementing an automatic login on my mac. I don't want the login window to appear at all and I need my mac to automatically log me in. I've implemented an auth plugin "**customPlugin**" for achieving the same, placed it at /Library/Security/SecurityAgentPlugins and have modified authorizationdb to look like this:

```
<array>
    <string>builtin:policy-banner</string>
    <string>customPlugin:setCreds</string>
    <string>NullAuthPlugin:before_loginwindow_login</string>
    <string>loginwindow:login</string>
    <string>NullAuthPlugin:before_builtin_login-begin</string>
    <string>builtin:login-begin</string>
    <string>builtin:reset-password,privileged</string>
    <string>builtin:forward-login,privileged</string>
    <string>builtin:auto-login,privileged</string>
    <string>builtin:authenticate,privileged</string>
    <string>PKINITMechanism:auth,privileged</string>
    <string>builtin:login-success</string>
    <string>loginwindow:success</string>
    <string>loginwindow:FDESupport,privileged</string>
    <string>HomeDirMechanism:login,privileged</string>
    <string>HomeDirMechanism:status</string>
    <string>MCXMechanism:login</string>
    <string>CryptoTokenKit:login</string>
    <string>loginwindow:done</string>
</array>
```

**NullAuthPlugin** simply logs system authorization context. The **customPlugin** does run and sets context values 'username' and 'password' to my credentials as confirmed by the logs dumped by **NullAuthPlugin**:

```
2020-12-23 10:28:40.054487+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:MechanismCreate: inPlugin=0x7fb0b2d167f0, inEngine=0x7fb0b2d16770, mechanismId='before_loginwindow_login'
2020-12-23 10:28:40.054700+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:MechanismCreate: err=0, *outMechanism=0x7fb0b2e454a0
2020-12-23 10:28:40.055989+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:MechanismInvoke: inMechanism=0x7fb0b2e454a0
2020-12-23 10:28:40.056129+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:PrintAuthState: pid=8358, ppid=1, euid=92, ruid=92
2020-12-23 10:28:40.056334+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:PrintAuthState: SessionGetInfo err=0, actualSessionID=100086, sessionAttr=0x30
2020-12-23 10:28:40.056568+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:PrintAuthState: GetSessionId err=0, sessionID=0x0
2020-12-23 10:28:40.056765+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:PrintAuthState: GetArguments err=-60008
2020-12-23 10:28:40.056957+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetContextValue key='username', value='administrator'
2020-12-23 10:28:40.057239+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetContextValue key='password', value='********'
2020-12-23 10:28:40.057538+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='authorize-right', value='system.login.console'
2020-12-23 10:28:40.057888+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='client-path', value='/System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app'
2020-12-23 10:28:40.058073+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='client-pid', value=8342
2020-12-23 10:28:40.058246+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='client-type', value='BNDL'
2020-12-23 10:28:40.058440+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='client-uid', value=0
2020-12-23 10:28:40.058569+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='creator-pid', value=8342
2020-12-23 10:28:40.058674+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='tries', value=0
2020-12-23 10:28:40.058854+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='reason' value=00 00 00 00
2020-12-23 10:28:40.059239+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:MechanismInvoke: err=0
2020-12-23 10:29:00.472632+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:MechanismCreate: inPlugin=0x7fb0b2d167f0, inEngine=0x7fb0b2f90f30, mechanismId='before_builtin_login-begin'
2020-12-23 10:29:00.472738+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:MechanismCreate: err=0, *outMechanism=0x7fb0b2f37c10
2020-12-23 10:29:00.473971+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:MechanismInvoke: inMechanism=0x7fb0b2f37c10
2020-12-23 10:29:00.474078+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:PrintAuthState: pid=8358, ppid=1, euid=92, ruid=92
2020-12-23 10:29:00.474213+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:PrintAuthState: SessionGetInfo err=0, actualSessionID=100086, sessionAttr=0x30
2020-12-23 10:29:00.474351+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:PrintAuthState: GetSessionId err=0, sessionID=0x0
2020-12-23 10:29:00.474484+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:PrintAuthState: GetArguments err=-60008
2020-12-23 10:29:00.474592+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetContextValue key='username', value='administrator'
2020-12-23 10:29:00.474690+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetContextValue key='password', value='********'
2020-12-23 10:29:00.474788+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetContextValue key='uid', value=502
2020-12-23 10:29:00.474883+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetContextValue key='gid', value=20
2020-12-23 10:29:00.474979+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetContextValue key='home', value='/Users/administrator'
2020-12-23 10:29:00.475074+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetContextValue key='longname', value='Administrator'
2020-12-23 10:29:00.475173+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetContextValue key='shell', value='/bin/bash'
2020-12-23 10:29:00.475271+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='authorize-right', value='system.login.console'
2020-12-23 10:29:00.475375+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='client-path', value='/System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app'
2020-12-23 10:29:00.475474+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='client-pid', value=8342
2020-12-23 10:29:00.475572+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='client-type', value='BNDL'
2020-12-23 10:29:00.475666+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='client-uid', value=0
2020-12-23 10:29:00.475759+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='creator-pid', value=8342
2020-12-23 10:29:00.475849+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='tries', value=0
2020-12-23 10:29:00.475953+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetHintValue key='reason' value=00 00 00 00
2020-12-23 10:29:00.476097+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetContextValue key='dsAttrTypeStandard:GeneratedUID' value=39 39 32 43 44 34 33 31 2d 35 46 41 34 2d 34 36 30 36 2d 38 43 46 33 2d 32 42 33 44 35 43 37 33 38 37 37 42 00
2020-12-23 10:29:00.476269+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> GetContextValue key='dsAttrTypeStandard:AuthenticationAuthority', value='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> <plist version="1.0"> <array>   <string>;ShadowHash;HASHLIST:&lt;SALTED-SHA512-PBKDF2,SRP-RFC5054-4096-SHA512-PBKDF2&gt;</string>   <string>;Kerberosv5;;administrator@LKDC:SHA1.A6D292D36146C71BAA8524AF45CF54502CBF48BE;LKDC:SHA1.A6D292D36146C71BAA8524AF45CF54502CBF48BE</string> </array> </plist> '
2020-12-23 10:29:00.476601+0530 0x5e2b7    Debug       0x0                  8358   SecurityAgent: (NullAuthPlugin) >>>-----> NullAuth:MechanismInvoke: err=0
```

But instead of carrying on with the login process as username and password are already available when **loginwindow:login** is called, it shows the login window and I still need to input username and password. Only after I do this, **builtin:login-begin** is called (in logs, you can see the 20 seconds difference between when NullAuthPlugin mechanisms **before_loginwindow_login** and **before_builtin_login-begin** are called).

Is there something else I need to be doing in my custom auth plugin other than just setting the context values 'username' and 'password' to achieve the automatic login function I'm aiming for?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; You need to set the values and then submit your verdict. You also need to disable the `loginwindow:login` done mechanism. There are easier ways to reach this goal without code.

By far the simplest way to auto login on a Mac is to just use the built in functionality for that. No code required!

If you are setting the context values you need to be sure to also call the plugin callbacks with a result as well. For example, `kAuthorizationResultAllow` is the one to set after you set your context values. Assuming that all the other mechs in the console login list agree it will let you in with a big caveat.

That big caveat is that you need to remove the built-in `loginwindow:login` mechanism from the list. When that loads it will always present its UI and wait for you to enter data. That's just how it works and the built in login window mech will not submit a verdict until you do so unless you are setting the system level automatic login hints. if you are needing to do that though then you might as well just use the OS auto login feature.

Of course FileVault will put a stop to all of these tricks by requiring you to unlock the disk as well. If you want to forward those credentials take a look at [how we do that in NoMADLogin](https://gitlab.com/orchardandgrove-oss/NoMADLogin-AD/-/blob/main/Mechs/CheckAD.swift).